# Restkit return value for postObject

Tags: ios, json, restkit, afnetworking

I am posting to my rails server using the post object method.

```
[manager postObject:recipe path:@"/api/recipes" parameters:@{ @"auth_token": fbAccessToken } success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"mappingResult: %@", mappingResult);
}];
```

This works as intended, however my Rails app is returning the json of the Recipe. How do I access this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All returned values are in `mappingResult` variable.

`RKMappingResult` object has many methods that will return the serialized JSON when set-up properly. Such methods are: `dictionary` and `array`. You can look at the [header](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/ObjectMapping/RKMappingResult.h) file for other methods.

Also be sure to read documentation that can be found on [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) website and a lot of things will be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the array method, however your answer made me realize that my response that I was sending was not in the proper form.